# Using a custom view for a taxonomy term page

Tags: 7, views

Using Drupal 7 and Views 7.x-3.0-beta3, what is the best way to have a taxonomy page use a custom view?

For example, in Path Auto I have a rule that points the URL alias countries/england towards taxonomy/term/44.

When a user visits countries/england I want to display a page created with Views, not the default taxonomy page.

I am populating the menu using Taxonomy Menu which doesn't yet support custom paths in Drupal 7.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe I am misunderstanding what you are saying, but Views comes with a view for taxonomy/term/%tid. Once enabled, when you visit http://example.com/taxonomy/term/44, Views will show its own page, and not the default page output from Drupal.

Comment: i tried doing the same but i got an access denied error...http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/72273/access-denied-error-for-taxonomy-view-page

Answer (score 4):

There are two modules that can pull this off for you. Either [tvi](http://drupal.org/project/tvi) or [taxonomy display](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_display). Both are quite buggy in Drupal 7 at the moment so it will take some tweaking to get them working properly.

I have a site using your setup with tvi but I had to manually enter the values into the tvi table to get it working and could not use taxonomy/term/% for the path of the views. I had to use pathalias_i_set_for_the_term/%. I tried out taxonomy display as it is in alpha but it had some errors with my setup and tvi was already hacked and working for me. I would suggest trying out taxonomy display first as it appears like it will be the better option moving forward.

Comment: I just used Taxonomy Display and it worked great. Before that I tried TVI but, like you, I would have had to manually add the entries to the DB. Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 0):

As kiamlaluno said, I think that you can do this out-of-the-box in views 7.x-3.0-beta3: you can add taxonomy name/id to "Filter Criteria" or "Contextual filter" to a basic new unformated view, then you can add a path to that display/view.

Comment: one last thing: how to change links of rendered tags to point to this my view?

Comment: I am also interested in finding an easy way for the terms now to point to my view (instead of making a new menu)

Answer (score 0):

Try this module: [Taxonomy Views Integrator](http://drupal.org/project/tvi) It allows you to theme every vocabulary or term with it's own view. Worked wonders for me. Also see this page: http://drupal.org/node/424168